# Performing a custom action when a given mocked void method is called

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I would like to be able for Mockito to **perform a custom action when a given void method is called**.

Say I have the following code:

```
@Autowired
private ProfileService profileService;

@Autowired
private ProfileDao profileDao;

private List<Profile> profiles;

@Before
public void setup() {
    Mockito.when(profileDao.findAll()).thenReturn(profiles);
    Mockito.when(profileDao.persist(any(Profile.class))).thenAddProfileToAboveList...
}

@Configuration
public static class testConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ProfileDao ProfileDao() {
        return mock(ProfileDao.class);
    }
}
```

Say I want to add a Profile instance to the profiles list. Can Mockito do that? If so how?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [Mockito.doAnswer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-).

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
   public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
       // make the changes you need here
   }})
 .when(mock).someMethod();
```

Comment: Can I get a bit more detail on this answer?  OP asked to add a Profile to `profiles`, but the code above mentions neither...  and the `profiles` list itself appears to be outside the scope of the inner class - and the linked documentation seems to be more focused on manipulating mocks than on calling arbitrary unmocked code.