# Mockito print message on void method call

Tags: java, mockito

I have a service with `void` method which i have mocked.
i want to log or `system.out.println("..")` when void method being hit.

```
public class MyService {

public void call(){
// do something.
}
}

private MyService mySerivce = mock(MyService.class);
```

i want to log a message from call method body how can i mock ? like i can use answer with non-void methods.

```
verify(myService, times(1)).call();

myService.call();

verify(my)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088465/performing-a-custom-action-when-a-given-mocked-void-method-is-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `spy` and verify its state after running the test (to be honest - you can do it also with `mock` but with `spy` you can test real object if you want):

```
//Given
MyService service = new MyService();
MyService serviceSpy = Mockito.spy(service);

//When
serviceSpy.call();

//Then
long count = Mockito.mockingDetails(serviceSpy)
      .getInvocations()
      .stream()
      .filter(i -> i.toString().contains("service.call()"))
      .count();

if (count > 0)
    System.out.println("Method was called " + count + " times.");
else
    System.out.println("Method wasn't called at all.");

//TODO: of course this isn't correct test because it hasn't any assertions.
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Of course you are right - I have read the question too fast. I have edited my answer so now it's displaying how to check number of invocations of method.